# How do I install Photoshop CS5 Extended from the CD?

Tags: 11.10, wine, photoshop

I'm quite new (or brand new) to Ubuntu.

I want to install my Adobe Photoshop CS5 Extended. I have purchased a licensed copy.

I downloaded WINE and ran the start up through that. Everything ran smoothly until it actually started installing. It barely starts and I get an error message from the  installation screen from Adobe Photoshop. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Wine's [AppDB entry for Photoshop CS5](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158&iTestingId=70153)

In the "Installs?" column it says "No, but has a workaround". Below you'll find some detailed instructions - try following them and see if it helps.